# how to remove table row id With jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have use two table.I want remove one row using particular table tr id.I use the  code

```
$("#tabDisplay1 #"+pmRowId).remove();  
$("#tabDisplay2 #"+pmRowId).remove();
```

But some time i have same id occuar  remove not working?

Comment: You can't have same `ID` in DOM. You can use `CLASS` for this

Comment: Elements in HTML should not have repeating IDs. YOu should try to use a combination of classes and Unique IDs. Post your generated HTML to help us understand this error.

Comment: If you want to use like this, u need to go with unique id. Id should be repeated for other rows

Comment: Apart from what the others say, it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nufX6/. The only reason I could imagine why it does not work is because selectors are evaluate from right to left and then duplicate IDs might mess things up. Hence: Don't use duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

An ID can be present only once in a document. You should

- use different id
- or use a class

I'd suggest the use of a class :

```
$("#tabDisplay1 ."+pmRowClass).remove();  
$("#tabDisplay2 ."+pmRowClass).remove();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/qVa99/)

Comment: No : jQuery uses document.getElementById to find an element when you provide the id.

Comment: I am also use same class.any other idea @dystroy

Comment: @Mariselvam: Do you mean that you have the same problem when using classes instead of IDs? Then the error must be somewhere else in your code. Or you have a logic error.

Comment: @MariselvamPanneerselvam I've added a demonstration. Maybe you have another error, as suggested by Felix.

Comment: i am also using same class @dystroy

Answer (score 0):

you should maintain the unique id for each rows, then only you can remove the expected rows.